# Fn Key Keycode?

Tags: 10.10, keyboard

I'm trying to remap my keyboard such that the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> acts as an additional <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, because the current one is in an awkward place (over by the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>).  I was planning on using xmodmap, which requires keycodes to work.  I have my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> keycode, which is 66, but to finish I need the keycode for the <kbd>Fn</kbd>.  Using xev and pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd>, I don't see anything.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key usually doesn't send a key code; it's handled by the BIOS, not by the OS.  You can sometimes get at it as an ACPI event.  (This is very much dependent on the exact computer model.)

Comment: Too bad.  Thanks for your help.  Here's to getting used to a function key next to the home and end keys!

Comment: This answer is not true anymore.  See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/462314/what-are-the-functions-of-the-bios-while-the-operating-system-is-running) post.